# Do the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ form a complete space?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following sets 
$$\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}, [0,1), [0,\infty).$$

For a subset of complete space to be complete, it must be the case that it is also closed. The set of irrational numbers, $[0,1)$ and $[0,\infty)$ are neither open or closed and so they cannot form a complete space. However, $\mathbb{Z}$ forms a complete space with the usual metric since any Cauchy Sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$ will become eventually constant and thus convergent.

Is this answer correct?

Comment: But $[0,\infty)$ is closed and $\mathbb{R} $\ $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed.

Comment: So $[0,\infty)$ is complete and $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is not complete, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

You got three out of four. From [Wikipedia on complete metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space), a subspace of a complete metric space is complete if and only if it is closed. $\Bbb{R}$ of course is complete, so the complete subspaces in your list are just the closed ones, which are $\Bbb{Z}$ and $[0, \infty)$.

Your direct argument for $\Bbb{Z}$ is good, and I think you can easily also give examples of Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ and $[0, 1)$ which do not converge in those subspaces. You might try proving directly that $[0, \infty)$ is complete.